# Swift can't retrieve images from parse.com

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I was using 6.4 of Xcode and it was working fine but when I updated to Xcode 7 it seems like query isn't working for photos.

I'm getting username on table view but the images not showing I get this error when testing on simulator iPhone 5:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

And when I test it on iPhone 6 I got this error :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>       (lldb)

and showing me a red thread on this line :

```
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
```

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495059 related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple now forcing dev to use ATS(HTTPS), but you can disable it in info.plist by adding this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
     </dict>
```

Should look like this [image]

Visit  [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html) for more details about ATS and please watch this [WWDC video session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=711)

Your second issue is explain below

`FPUser.currentUser` can return nil if user logged out, and you are using `!` force unwrapping and then `calling username`, so if user is not logged in then `currentUser` will return nil and you will end up calling `username` on `nil`, hence you are getting this crash, you should do something like this.

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser()
{
   query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user.username!) 
}
else
{
   // show login ui 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, if i removed the `!` i'm getting error i can't build, what should i do ?

Comment: You can sorrund this in if let

Comment: how can i add that to info.plist ? my info.plist looks like this : http://cut.by/GUhyY

Comment: Add new entry NSAppTransportSecurity and set its type NSDictionary and then add an item NSAllowsArbitraryLoads and set its type to boolean and set its value to true

Comment: thank you so much worked! I really appreciate it, Accepted answer :)

Comment: I have added link to wwdc session, you must watch that session.

Answer (score 0):

Apple is now forcing HTTPS connections, that is the App Transport Security message. You are still sending over clear text HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can i do that?