# iOS9: Will NSAllowsArbitraryLoads=True be allowed for a release in the App Store?

Tags: ios, ios9

Apple has changed its current **App Transport Security** model with the release of iOS 9. Since this I have the issue that my App doesn't trust certain web services anymore and will terminate with an error. I found a solution to "fix" this error and I'm wondering if the following solution which I added to the *Info.plist* file will prevent the App from being released in the Apple App Store.

```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <dict>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      <true/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  </dict>
```

Does anybody know this?

**Update:**

Question is a duplicate to:

[Does App Store reject submission if NSAllowsArbitraryLoads set to YES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534304/does-app-store-reject-submission-if-nsallowsarbitraryloads-set-to-yes)

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456848/ios9-does-not-load-insecure-resources-from-a-secure-page-ssl-https/32458692#32458692

Comment: Thx, but this doesn't answer my question - no reference to App Store releases. The answer provides another solution for my initial problem.

Comment: This is just a reference for you to get more information about revised App Transport Security by Apple.

Comment: AFAICS it is the same question though but there is no real answer there either

Comment: yeah, I will remove my question if I won't get an answer to my question in the next 3 to 4 days. But currently it is more likely that my question will be answered than the other question, I guess.

Comment: It depends whether your app has a good reason to do this. A web browser that needs to access arbitrary URLs might. But if you have a need to access some very specific URL that doesn't meet security requirements, then turning App Transport Security off globally will not go down well.

Comment: Apple has not stated that there is a requirement to use https with TLS 1.2 and forward security, just that it is the default and is urging support. Apple has provided options to use non-conforming http. Apple allows horrible security, much worse than http, just look at the horrible security seen Q&A here on SO.

Comment: So is there an answer for this? I don't think that kind of thing would happen. I want to update my app but this situation bugs me. Even though there is no officially documented thing about rejection in case usage of NSAllowArbitrartyLoads.

Answer (score 8):

Of course they'll allow you to submit apps with that setting.  They added that override because some apps can't feasibly be released without allowing non-HTTPS requests.  It will be a long time before it will be practical to ban unencrypted HTTP.

You may have to provide an explanation of why you're using that exception, of course.

Comment: Not that long. Turns out was about 1 year. From Dec 2016 HTTPS will be required except for the web view.

Comment: Web browsers have always been the major exception (hence my "long time"), but this policy has lots of other problems, such as the fact that you can't get a valid SSL cert for a Bonjour domain (requiring... shall we say "interesting" workarounds).  I'm watching this section of Stack Overflow pretty carefully to try to help folks who run into those issues, but I expect that there will still be a number of apps that will require exceptions, and I suspect Apple will grant such exceptions, assuming the reasons for supporting HTTP are valid (e.g. user-entered URLs).

Comment: Could be; that's our situation, the user can enter any random data feed URL they want, not under our control.

Comment: I would urge you to file a bug and tell what you want to do, and explain why HTTPS isn't possible.  Refer to that bug when you submit and ask for an exception.